# Positioning buttons in menu header polymer

Tags: polymer

How to place `paper-icon-button`in right corner of application header ?
Now my icon floats under title and it's not looking good.
Screenshot below [image: Screenshot of application]

My element Code:

```
<polymer-element name="sidebar-layout" attributes="selected" noscript>
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/sidebar-layout.css">
        <core-scaffold>
            <core-header-panel  navigation flex mode="seamed">
                <core-toolbar>Menu</core-toolbar>
               <core menu theme="core-light-theme">
                <core-item icon="info-outline" label="Notes" active?="{{selected == 'notes-page'}}"><a is="pushstate-anchor" href="/notes"></a></core-item>
                <core-item icon="key" label="Logowanie" active?="{{selected == 'login-page'}}}}"><a is="pushstate-anchor" href="/login"></a></core-item>
                <core-item icon="key" label="Pozalogowaniu" active?="{{selected == 'main-page'}}}}"><a is="pushstate-anchor" href="/main-page"></a></core-item>
               </core>
           </core-header-panel>

            <div tool>
                <content select=".title"></content>
                <paper-icon-button id="morebutton"
                                   icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <content></content>
            </div>
        </core-scaffold>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you can do this using CSS pretty nicely here's a workaround that makes more semantic sense, adding a `flex` attribute to the `<content>` element or a `<span>` tag like I have dont below.

```
<polymer-element name="sidebar-layout" attributes="selected" noscript>
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/sidebar-layout.css">
        <core-scaffold>
            <core-header-panel  navigation flex mode="seamed">
                <core-toolbar>Menu</core-toolbar>
               <core menu theme="core-light-theme">
                <core-item icon="info-outline" label="Notes" active?="{{selected == 'notes-page'}}"><a is="pushstate-anchor" href="/notes"></a></core-item>
                <core-item icon="key" label="Logowanie" active?="{{selected == 'login-page'}}}}"><a is="pushstate-anchor" href="/login"></a></core-item>
                <core-item icon="key" label="Pozalogowaniu" active?="{{selected == 'main-page'}}}}"><a is="pushstate-anchor" href="/main-page"></a></core-item>
               </core>
           </core-header-panel>

            <div tool>
                <content select=".title"></content>
                <span flex></span>
                <paper-icon-button id="morebutton"
                                   icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <content></content>
            </div>
        </core-scaffold>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

This `<span>` tag with the `flex` attribute takes just the amount of space that it lets the icon fit in the far right.

More about the `flex` attribute at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/layout-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about [layout attributes](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html).

Specifically in this case the attribute `justified` does the job

```
<div horizontal layout justified tool>
    <content select=".title"></content>
    <paper-icon-button id="morebutton" icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
</div>
```